# Can i Update the Data in List View?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I've a form in which I've data of Products of one store. i am accessing product Name and Price by just simply Providing Product code into other form, now here i want that when i open my Products form in which i have used list view to show already added products, i can easily click on any row , click edit button and the selected list view row becomes edit able , i simply update data in list view (by writing it in list view) and then click on save and it just automatically save data into my data base using update query..

the code through which i am loading products data in list view is :

```
 private void frm4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fnc_LoadProductsInfo(lvProducts);

        }

        private void fnc_LoadProductsInfo(ListView lv)
        {
            string sql;

            sql = "";
            sql += "SELECT * FROM ProductLog ORDER BY ItemNo";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            clsConnection clsCon = new clsConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataReader sdr;

            clsCon.fnc_ConnectToDB(ref con);

            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            lv.Items.Clear();
            ListViewItem lvItem;

            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                lvItem = new ListViewItem();

                lvItem.Text = Convert.ToString(sdr.GetValue(sdr.GetOrdinal("ItemNo")));
                lvItem.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(sdr.GetValue(sdr.GetOrdinal("ProductCode"))));
                lvItem.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(sdr.GetValue(sdr.GetOrdinal("ProductName"))));
                lvItem.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(sdr.GetValue(sdr.GetOrdinal("ProductPrice"))));
               // lvItem.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(sdr.GetValue(sdr.GetOrdinal("TotalPrice"))));
                //lvItem.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(sdr.GetValue(sdr.GetOrdinal("Password"))));
                lv.Items.Add(lvItem);
                lvItem = null;
            }

            // lblTotalRecords.Text = Convert.ToString(lv.Items.Count);

            sdr.Close();
            sdr = null;
            cmd = null;
            con.Close();
            con = null;


        }
```

is it possible to make list view editable in it's own column and if yes then how can i do it?? any other suggestion will also be appreciable ...

Comment: On a listView you only can use inplace edit in the first column. Subitems are not editables.
You can configure a gridView to have a similar look and feel that listview and have all columns editable.

Comment: you can use gridview for your requirements